# Why do not Easy Mobile Pro scripts know about each other?

Tags: unity, android, build-process

I am getting this error when I try to build the project:

```
Assets\EasyMobile\Scripts\Modules\NativeAPIs\NativeUI\Nati 
veUI_AlertPopup.cs(68,17): error CS0103: The name 'AndroidNativeAlert' does not exist in the current context
```

I tried adding this to my NativeUI_AlertPopup.cs:

```
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        using EasyMobile.Internal.StoreReview.Android;
    #endif
```

Hint says unnecessary using.
Googling, searching Unity EMP forum and thread did not bring any results.
Unity version 2019.2 .net 4.x EMP 2.5
If I try adding a breakpoint it says:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unable to find a corresponding location.
```

AndroidNativeAlert is a static class, have have no clue why it can't been seen from the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the EMP folder from the assets folder and reinstalling it seems to put it right.

Comment: You can accept your own answer using the checkmark on the left.